# changing label text with button click

Tags: c#, button, label

I need to change the text of label on the button click, but it's not working and giving me  run time error.I've got separate class for LABEL and separate for BUTTON.This is dummy code.the real code contains locations and sizes for both label and button.Everything is created dynamically. Thanks!

```
   /-------------------------------------LABEL class-------------------------------/
   private Label label1;

   public Label getLabel1()
   {
       return label1;
   }

   public LABEL()
   {
       label1 = new Label();
   }

    public void print()
    {            
        label1.Text = "x";
        Controls.Add(label1);
    }//

  /-------------------------------------BUTTON class----------------------------------/
    private Button button1;

    public BUTTON()
    {

    }

    public void print()
    {
        button1 = new Button();
        button1.Click +=new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        Controls.Add(button1);
    }

     public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        LABEL label = new LABEL();
        label.getLabel1().Text = "y";
     }
```

Comment: You didn't mention the error it was giving at runtime

Comment: Thanks to MatthewRz to error is fixed, but it still wont display anything

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){label1.Text = "Hi";label1.Refresh();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change the text of a null-referenced label:

```
// Label Class
private Label label1;
public Label getLabel1()
{
    return label1;
}
// Button Class
LABEL label1 = new LABEL();
label1.getLabel1().Text = "y";
// getLabel1 is returning null, because you have not initialized label1
```

In order for the code to work, you have to change the following:

```
public LABEL()
{
    label1 = new Label();
}

public void print()
{
    label1.Text = "x";
    Controls.Add(label1);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does make sense, but it still doesnt do anything. it stopped to crash though. thanks!

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't do anything? Do you mean that it does not change the text of `label1`?

Comment: Yes, it doesnt change the text, as it supposed to

Comment: Hmm, I am not too sure why it doesn't. I will edit my post if I figure it out.