# Changing label text on button click that also executes other methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am trying to update a label on my windows form with statistics from another methods execution that scrapes a webpage and creates a zip file of the links and creates a sitemap page. Preferably this button would run the scraping operations and report the statistics properly. Currently the scraping process is working fine but the label I want to update with statistics data is not changing on the button click. Here is what my code looks like now:

```
protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Run scrape work
    scrape_work(sender, e);
    //Run statistics work
    statistics(sender, e);
}

protected void scrape_work(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Scraping work (works fine)
}

protected void statistics(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (scriptBox.Text != null)
    {
        count += 1;
    }
    var extra = eventsBox.Text;
    var extraArray = extra.Split('\n');
    foreach (var item in extraArray)
    {
        count += 1;
    }
    //scrapeNumLbl is label I want to display text on
    scrapeNumLbl.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

Would I have to use threading for this process or is there some other way I can get this process to work? I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335507/changing-label-text-with-button-click) solution but was having the same issue where the code runs but the label does not update. Any help would be greatly appreciated, this minor thing has been bugging me for hours now.

Comment: I have been debugging and it is reaching statistics() it is just not reloading the page with updated label

Comment: Just debug your code and see how long it takes to complete `scrape_work()`. Just like @markaaronky suggested may be your code is not reaching `statistics()`.

Comment: Your statistics method won't fire until your scrape_work method has completed. If scrape_work takes 20 minutes to complete then you'll have to wait the entire 20 minutes before statistics is called. We have no idea what scriptBox or eventsBox are so we are unable to tell whether it's just a timing issue or whether something is failing along the way meaning the code never gets to scrapNumLbl.Text = count.ToString();

Comment: @HandbagCrab using breakpoints in my code I have been able to see that my program is reaching to `scrapeNumLbl.Text = count.ToString()`. `scriptBox` and `eventsBox` are just a series of links in a textbox that I am feeding into `scrape_work` to scrape. `scrape_work` simply prints the desired links to a hidden label on the page that is then read and written into a series of zip files. I'm thinking the issue with it could be that the page is never called to reload and so the label never updates. Is this a possibility based on your knowledge/experience? I'm still quite new to C# altogether

Comment: When you set text on a label the text is immediately displayed. That is as long as you're not blocking the UI thread. Windows will ensure the screen gets updated and you shouldn't need to call mylabel.Refresh() or this.Invalidate() or DoEvents().

Comment: @HandbagCrab I think the error is that the request ends after the zip file is sent to the user's downloads on the button click. I am working on creating a download link for the zip file rather than forcing the files to download and ending the request there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this by writing the path to the zip file to a label button on the form rather than sending it right to download on the client's browser on button click. The issue was that the request was ending after the zip file was sent for download. To ensure that both methods ran at the proper time I moved the call to the `scrape_work` method to inside of of `statistics`

In order for the path to be clickable and the file to download properly I had to make the "label" in the form a LinkButton in the .aspx page

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lblDownload" runat="server" CssClass="xclass" OnClick="lblDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And made the `lblDownload_Click` run like the following:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=zipFiles.zip");
string folder = Server.MapPath("~/zip");
string endPath = folder + "/zipFiles.zip";
Response.TransmitFile(endPath);
Response.End();
```

Running it this way the page reloads with the new labels properly written and the zip file available to download as well.

Answer (score 0):

ASSUMING THIS CODE IS RUNNING SYNCHRONOUSLY (you aren't threading the scraping in a call I don't see), Are you sure you are reaching the code that sets the label text?  I simplified your code as below (removing the iteration over the array and just setting the label text to a stringified integer) and am not having any trouble changing the text of a label.

```
namespace SimpleTest
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scrape_work(sender, e);
        statistics(sender, e);
    }

    protected void scrape_work(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Scraping work (works fine)
    }

    protected void statistics(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 666;

        scrapeNumLbl.Text = count.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Result:
[image]

Comment: Yes I have used breakpoints to ensure that it is reaching the code to set the label text. I tried this solution and the label still did not update. Could it perhaps be something to do with the scraping work done in the scrape_work method that prevents the page from updating the label? I can get the label to change on a button click that just references statistics but optimally I want the two to run at the same time